# thread lock necessary for processing queues + Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a queue in which i have to use it in several threads, so is it necessary to acquire the thread lock to avoid conflicts while processing this single queue, because i know it is necessary to acquire thread lock for variables or other resources, but little confused for queues.

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the Queue in the module Queue, it will take care of the locking for you. See this page for more information: http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html ("The Queue class in this module implements all the required locking semantics.")

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a mutex(lock) which will protect ALL accesses to the queue. Just make `pop` and `push` use it.

A possible performance wise better solution might  be to use more fine grain locking.